(/maketitle) Missing number, treated as zero,using overleaf

\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,hyperfootnotes=true,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=red,
}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}
%\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

% \usepackage{caption}
% \captionsetup[figure]{name={Fig.},labelsep=period}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}} 
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} 

%%%Author definitions
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
\tsc{EP}
\tsc{PMS}
\tsc{BEC}
\tsc{DE}
%%%

\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\let\printorcid\relax  %可去掉页面下方的ORCID(s)
\shorttitle{XXX}
\shortauthors{XXX}

\title [mode = title]{XXX}                      





\author[1]{XX}


\credit{XX}
\affiliation[1]{XX}


\author[2]{XX}
    

\author[3]{XX}
\cormark[1]
\credit{XX}
\affiliation[3]{XX}




\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author.}
\cortext[]{E-mail address: XXX


\begin{abstract}
AAA
\end{abstract}



\begin{highlights}
\item AA
\item AA
\item AA

\end{highlights}

\begin{keywords}
AAA
\end{keywords}



\maketitle



MWE
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,hyperfootnotes=true,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{cas-dc}

\begin{document}

\title [mode = title]{XXX}                      


\author[1]{XX}

\credit{XX}
\affiliation[1]{XX}

\author[2]{XX}

\author[3]{XX}
\cormark[1]
\credit{XX}
\affiliation[3]{XX}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author.}
\cortext[]{E-mail address: XXX}

\begin{abstract}
AAA
\end{abstract}

\begin{highlights}
\item AA
\item AA
\item AA

\end{highlights}

\begin{keywords}
AAA
\end{keywords}

\maketitle
\end{document}


Package hyperref Warning: Ignoring empty anchor on input line 38.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \__int_eval_end: 
l.38 \maketitle
               
? 


unrelated but \def\floatpagepagefraction{1} makes p floats unusable and will almost always ensure that floats are forced to the end of the document.

\cortext[]{E-mail address: XXX is missing a }

The psoted code give Runaway argument? {E-mail address: XXX  ! Paragraph ended before \cortext  was complete. not the error you ask about, and the screenshot of an error message is clearly from a different document that has \maketitle on line 186. Please edit your question so that you show the error you get from the code posted

Can you help me ?when i use overleaf compile, I meet \maketitle  Missing number, treated as zero, Where Is the code error?

I added an example that produces that error/

I have no idea about this class but the error goes if you replace \cortext[]{E-mail address: XXX} by \cortext[cor1]{E-mail address: XXX}

\cortext[]{E-mail address: XXX} has already } ,I want to know how to fix this problem,can you give specific solution

It does not have a } in the code you posted here, and that is the code we can see. Whatever is in your original document does not help anyone answer, but see my comment above (and the corrected example that does give the error) it looks like you should not use []  as the argument.

Thankou, I soved, I will try to compile

\affiliation needs a key-value interface.
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  fleqn,
  hyperfootnotes=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  allcolors=blue
]{cas-dc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

% \usepackage{caption}
% \captionsetup[figure]{name={Fig.},labelsep=period}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}% not together with algpseudocode
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=red,
}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}} 
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} 

\let\printorcid\relax  %可去掉页面下方的ORCID(s)

\begin{document}

\shorttitle{SHORT}
\shortauthors{autshort}

\title [mode = title]{LONG TITLE}

\author[1]{AA}
\cormark[1]
\credit{creditAA}
\affiliation[1]{organization=orgAA}
\ead{AA@mail.com}

\author[2]{BB}
\author[3]{CC}
\credit{creditCC}
\affiliation[3]{organization=XX}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author.}
\cortext[1]{E-mail address: AA@mail.com}

\begin{abstract}
AAA
\end{abstract}

\begin{highlights}
\item AA
\item AA
\item AA
\end{highlights}

\begin{keywords}
AAA
\end{keywords}

\maketitle

\end{document}

Don't load both algorithmicx and algpseudocode: decide which one.
Also, hyperref and cleveref should be loaded last.

